# $routeProvider / $locationProvider not a function in AngularJS Routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to create so-called 'SEO-friendly' URLs in AngularJS.

In my script.js for the routing I have:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.html5Mode(true);
    when('/blog', {
        templateUrl: 'blog.html',
        controller: 'BlogController'
    }).
    when('/page/ideas', {
        templateUrl: 'ideas.html',
        controller: 'IdeasController'
    }).
    otherwise({
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
    });
}]);

app.controller("BlogController", function($scope) {
    $scope.title = 'Blog';
});

app.controller("IdeasController", function($scope) {
    $scope.title = 'Ideas';
});
```

To remove the # from the URL, I am enabling the html5 mode with:

```
$routeProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

however, this results in the following error:

> Failed to instantiate module exampleApp due to:
>   TypeError: $routeProvider.html5Mode is not a function

Does anyone have a solution for this issue? It means that the content will not display from the views because of it.

**Edit**: for anyone wondering, the working code is:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/blog', {
            templateUrl: 'blog.html',
            controller: 'BlogController'
        }).
        when('/page/ideas', {
            templateUrl: 'ideas.html',
            controller: 'IdeasController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            templateUrl: 'home.html'
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);
```

Comment: Try using the `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` instead. html5Mode is a method of $locationProvider.

Comment: Hmm, now I get: ReferenceError: when is not defined OR ReferenceError: $locationProvider is not defined

Comment: You need to inject $locationProvider in the same way you do with $routeProvider

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`html5mode` method is available there on `$locationProvider` provider.

You should include `$locationProvider` in your config phase to make that dependency available in config block & then enable `html5mode` for `#` free URL.

**Code**

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

   //$routerProvider code here

   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

Additionally you have to add `<base href="/"`> tag on the `index.html` page

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you.

Comment: @JWTomic Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Comment: Configuring $locationProvider will remove the hashtag from the application URL but, application will not load correctly. To resolve this, you have to add a base tag in the head section of  the index page. `<base href="http://yourwebsitebase/" `

Comment: @biology.info thanks for heads up, I added the mentioned thing, Thanks :)

Comment: @biology.info may I know where should I?

Comment: Also note that the method has a capital M for Mode (html5Mode, not html5mode).  I spent more time than I want to admit chasing this down.

Comment: I used `html5Mode` itself in the code, I don't understand what I'm missing here ?